# How to decode raw png data from Assimp to CGImage?

Tags: cgimage, assimp

I am using `Assimp` and when using FBX with embedded textures, Assimp provides the embedded texture data in the following [struct `aiTexture`'s `pcData` slot](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/structai_texture.html#a97dcffdd5651f20605750820dab897a7). The documentation for `pcData` says:

> Appropriate decoders (such as libjpeg, libpng, D3DX, DevIL) are
>   required to load theses textures. aiTexture::mWidth specifies the size
>   of the texture data in bytes, aiTexture::pcData is a pointer to the
>   raw image data

I understand that `pcData` will have the png header, chunks etc and `libPNG` can give me back the actual image data with other specs (width, height etc).

**What is the native iOS/macOS API to do this instead of using `libPNG`?**
For example: [`CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider` `source`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454993-cgimagecreatewithpngdataprovider?language=objc) property describes it as `a data provider supplying PNG encoded data`. I tried with some code like this but that doesn't work:

```
                 CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = NULL;
                 dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL,
                                                            (const void*)texture->pcData,
                                                             texture->mWidth,
                                                             rgbReleaseRampData);
                  if(dataProvider) {
                        NSLog(@" ********* Created image data provider ");
                  }

                  // fails at this line            
                  CGImageRef  imageRef =   CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(dataProvider, 
                                             NULL,false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least for iOS/macOS; it seems to be a problem with the `assimp` library.

The following, if not the perfect fix, works:

adding a `uint_8` to hold raw image data in `texture.h`:

```
uint8_t *rawImageData;
```

Then reinterpret the `pcData` in `FBXConverter.cpp` as such:

```
 out_tex->pcData = reinterpret_cast< aiTexel * >(const_cast<Video&>( video   
).RelinquishContent());
 out_tex->rawImageData = reinterpret_cast< uint8_t * >(out_tex->pcData);
```

fixes the above problem. Without reinterpreting the `pcData`, in iOS/macOS one gets the invalid memory address for the memory buffer.

With the above fix, generating an image object requires only the following:

```
const struct aiTexture *aiTexture = aiScene->mTextures[index];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:aiTexture->pcData
                                   length:aiTexture->mWidth];
self.imageDataProvider =
    CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)imageData);
NSString* format = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:aiTexture->achFormatHint];
if([format isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
    DLog(@" Created png embedded texture ");
    self.image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(
        self.imageDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
}
if([format isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
    DLog(@" Created jpg embedded texture");
    self.image = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(
        self.imageDataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
}
```

[The GH Issue.](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/issues/1407#issuecomment-326763191)